# Merge 2 tables into 1 single Table in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I merge 2 tables into 1 table in T-SQL? I tried merging with full outer join which helps in joining 2 tables but with "customer Account" 2 times. I need all the columns from table A and Table B with only once "Customer Account Field" and all the rest of the columns from table A and Table B.ields.

Here is my example in more detail:

**Table A** - my first Table with 5 columns:

[image]

**Table B** - my second table with 6 columns:

[image]

I'm expecting the output like this:

Output with all fields in table A and in Table B but the common field only once:

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify which RDBMS you use: `mssql` or `mysql`? You tagged with `mysql` and `tsql` and T-SQL cannot be used in `mysql`. But in mssql it can. So which one of them?

Comment: Try INNER JOIN. So select * from tableA a inner join tableB b on a.cust# = bcust#

Comment: @AlexYu. I'm using T-sql.

Comment: @Chuck. Yeah, I can use Inner join, but inner join fetch only the matching records form table A and Table B. But I need all the customer account from Table A and table B.

Comment: @AlexYu. Thank you, I removed the Mysql Tag from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the required(all) columns from t1 and t2 to the select statement

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.customeraccount, t2.customeraccount) as customeraccount,
t1.BasicCardType,
t2.MonthlySet
FROM table1 t1
FULL JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.customeraccount = t2.customeraccount;
```

Answer (score 0):

(Edited based on comments): Join the tables on the CustomerAccount ID field (giving you entries that exist in both tables), then add a union for all entries that only exist in table A, then add a union for entries that only exist in table B. In principle:

```
-- get entries that exist in both tables
select Table_A.CustomerAccount, TableAField1, TableAField2, TableBField1, TableBField2
from Table_A
join Table_B on Table_A.CustomerAccount = Table_B.CustomerAccount
-- get entries that only exist in table_a
union select Table_A.CustomerAccount, TableAField1, TableAField2, null, null
from Table_A
where Table_A.CustomerAccount not in (select CustomerAccount from Table_B)
-- get entries that only exist in table_B
union select Table_B.CustomerAccount, null, null, TableBField1, TableBField2
from Table_B
where Table_B.CustomerAccount not in (select CustomerAccount from Table_A)
```

Comment: I tried with "Join". But it is pulling the matching reords from table A and Table B. I need all the customer Accounts from both Table A and Table B. If you could check my images in my questions, it will be more clear.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought CustomerAccount would exist/match in both tables. I have updated the answer to allow for entries that exist only in one or the other table. I see that Chidambaram's solution is far more elegant though.